# xrdp on Ubuntu with separate de for each user

Tags: server, remote-desktop, mate, cinnamon, xrdp

A colleague of mine installed Ubuntu Mate on our GPU-Server and xrdp for remote control. We can connect to this PC from Windows 7 using the Windows remote desktop software. Now, for his user almost everything works fine, when he logs in remotely. A few glitches such as: Firefox wont start (segmentation fault) or similar. For my user (I am also root and have all privileges), I cannot even move Windows, all start on top left and I simply cannot move them around. Most applications wont start and I cannot use keyboard shortcuts like CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal.
Now I would like to have mate as default desktop and for example cinnamon for my user, when I login. I tried to write "cinnamon" and "cinnamon2d" into the .xsession and .Xclients files and it wont work after a reboot. Also I tried to use it as standard de in the /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh file and it doesnt work either. I find the following errors in .xsession-errors:

```
...
...
...
X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
 Major opcode of failed request: 109 (X_ChangeHosts)
 Value in failed request: 0x5
 Serial number of failed request: 6
 Current serial number in output stream: 8
/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh: 3: [: x: unexpected operator
/usr/bin/cinnamon2d: line 2: 1465 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

cinnamon2d
#mate-session
#. /etc/X11/Xsession
```

I tried a few things and at this point I would like to ask for your expertise and help me out.

Thanks in advance!